# Using Galerkin's method to find an approximate solution

Tags: approximation-theory

How we can use Galerkin's method to find an approximate solution of

\begin{align}
x''(t)+ tx(t) &= 1, \\
x(0)  &= x(1) = 0,
\end{align}

using $t(1-t)$ and $t^2(1-t)$ as expansion function?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the equations imposed by Galerkin's method? If so, please try to elaborate.

Comment: @ccorn Actually, I don't have enough information about that, I want to have a general solution with descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found my answer.

Let $A \underline \alpha = b $. According to [Galerkin's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method) we have

$$ a_{ij} = \langle \varphi _{ni}, L \varphi_{ni} \rangle, \quad\quad b_i = \langle \varphi_{ni}, y \rangle $$
and 
‎‎\begin{align*}‎‎
‎\varphi_{21} & = t (1+t), & \varphi_{22} & = t^2(1-t), \\‎
L \varphi_{21} & = 2 + t^2 - t^3, & L \varphi_{23} & = 2- 6t + t^3 - t^4.
‎\end{align*}‎‎‎
then
‎‎\begin{align*}‎‎
‎\langle‎\varphi_{21},L‎\varphi_{21}‎‎\rangle &‎ =‎ ‎\int_0^1 ‎t(1-t) ‎(-2+t^2 -‎ ‎t^3) ‎dt = ‎0.3967‎ ‎\\‎
‎\langle‎‎\varphi_{21},L‎‎\varphi_{22}\rangle & = ‎‎‎‎\int_0^1 t(1-t)^2- 6t + t^3 - t^4) dt = 0.1571 \\‎
‎\langle‎\varphi_{22},L‎‎\varphi_{22}\rangle & = ‎‎‎‎\int_0^1 t^2(1-t)(2-6t+t(t^2 - t^3)) dt =0.1274 \\
‎\langle‎\varphi_{22},L‎‎\varphi_{21}‎‎\rangle & = ‎‎‎‎‎‎\int_0^1 (t^2-t^3)(-2+t^2 -t^3) dt = 0.1571
‎\end{align*}‎‎‎
‎\begin{align*}‎‎
‎\langle‎‎\varphi_{21}, 1\rangle &‎ =‎ ‎\int_0^1 t‎ -‎ ‎t^2 ‎dt = ‎0.‎1667‎ ‎\\‎
‎\langle‎‎\varphi_{22}, 1‎‎‎‎\rangle &‎ =‎ ‎\int_0^1 ‎t^2 -‎ ‎t^3 ‎dt =‎ ‎‎0.0833
‎\end{align*}‎‎
finally
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.3967&0.1571\\‎
0.1571&0.1274
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
‎\alpha_1\\‎
‎\alpha_2‎
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0.1227\\‎
0.0833
\end{bmatrix}‎‎$$
$$ \Longrightarrow\alpha‎_1=‎0.520‎\qquad‎\text{‏and}‎‎‎‎\quad‎‎\alpha_2=0.‎012 $$